# Establishing a persistent connection to the server with Long Polling

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I'm a client and i do not have access to server so i have been using periodic polls to get data from an API endpoint url (JSON Format) and now i want to avoid making too many requests to check for real-time data... instead i have modified script to establish a persistent connection with server and emulate server push behavior, where the server can send new data to the client as soon as it becomes available, rather than requiring the client to poll the server at regular intervals. The script is focused to extract/print only titles from API, when script runs it prints and duplicate over and over latest title by split second.. if there is a new title than last one it starts printing every split second.

Now my question: Is my script sending requests every split second & printing last titles over and over because i don't really get it how it's working.

```
import requests

def long_poll():
    while True:
        try:
            response = requests.get('https://example.com/api', timeout=280)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                data = response.json()
                for item in data:
                    if item['source'] != 'Twitter':
                        print(item['title'])
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    long_poll()
```

Here is result from the script as an example:

Latest Title: "Stack Overflow Has Updated It's Website"

```
Stack Overflow Has Updated It's Website
Stack Overflow Has Updated It's Website
Stack Overflow Has Updated It's Website
Stack Overflow Has Updated It's Website
```

(New title comes)
Latest Title: "Here Are 10 Interested Things That Make Stack OverFlow Helpful"

```
Here Are 10 Interested Things That Make Stack OverFlow Helpful
Here Are 10 Interested Things That Make Stack OverFlow Helpful
Here Are 10 Interested Things That Make Stack OverFlow Helpful
Here Are 10 Interested Things That Make Stack OverFlow Helpful
Here Are 10 Interested Things That Make Stack OverFlow Helpful
```